# C++ expression cannot be used as a function: (_f2)(arg);

Tags: c++

A few years ago i had my Open tibia server, it's old source engine, previous compiled at gcc 4.7+, already i try to compile it at newest debian, my gcc version is: 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)

> error: no match for call to ‘(Task) (Game*&)’
> (*_f2)(arg);
>
> error displays: expression cannot be used as a function
> (_f2)(arg);

```
template<class ArgType>
class TCallList : public SchedulerTask{
public:
    TCallList(
        boost::function<bool(Game*, ArgType)> f1,
        Task* f2,
        std::list<ArgType>& call_list,
        int64_t interval) :
            _f1(f1), _f2(f2), _list(call_list), _interval(interval)
    {
        //
    }
    
    virtual void operator()(Game* arg)
    {
        if(_eventid != 0){
            bool ret = _f1(arg, _list.front());
            _list.pop_front();

            if(ret){
                if(_list.empty()){
                    //callback function
                    if(_f2){
                        (_f2)(arg);
                        delete _f2;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //fire next task
                    SchedulerTask* newTask = new TCallList(_f1, _f2, _list, _interval);
                    newTask->setTicks(_interval);
                    newTask->setEventId(this->getEventId());
                    arg->addEvent(newTask);
                }
            }
        }
    }

private:
    boost::function<bool(Game*, ArgType)> _f1;
    Task* _f2;

    std::list<ArgType> _list;
    int64_t _interval;
};

template<class ArgType>
SchedulerTask* makeTask(int64_t ticks,
    boost::function<bool(Game*, ArgType)>* f1,
    std::list<ArgType>& call_list,
    int64_t interval,
    Task* f2)
{
    TCallList<ArgType>* t = new TCallList<ArgType>(f1, f2, call_list, interval);
    t->setTicks(ticks);
    return t;
}
```

> Scheduler.cpp

```
    #ifndef __OTSERV_SCHEDULER_H__
#define __OTSERV_SCHEDULER_H__

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include "otsystem.h"

class Game;

class SchedulerTask {
public:
    SchedulerTask() {
        _eventid = 0;
        _cycle = 0;
  }

    virtual ~SchedulerTask()
    {
        //
    }

    // definition to make sure lower cycles end up front
    // in the priority_queue used in the scheduler
    inline bool operator<(const SchedulerTask& other) const
    {
        return getCycle() > other.getCycle();
    }

    virtual void operator()(Game* arg) = 0;

    virtual void setEventId(uint32_t id)
    {
        _eventid = id;
    }

    inline uint32_t getEventId() const
    {
        return _eventid;
    }

    virtual void setTicks(const int64_t ticks)
    {
        _cycle = OTSYS_TIME() + ticks;
    }

    inline int64_t getCycle() const
    {
        return _cycle;
    }

protected:
    uint32_t _eventid;
    int64_t _cycle;
};

class TSchedulerTask : public SchedulerTask{
public:
    TSchedulerTask(boost::function1<void, Game*> f) :
        _f(f)
    {
        //
    }

    virtual ~TSchedulerTask()
    {
        //
    }

    virtual void operator()(Game* arg)
    {
        _f(arg);
    }

protected:
    boost::function1<void, Game*> _f;
};

SchedulerTask* makeTask(boost::function1<void, Game*> f);
SchedulerTask* makeTask(int64_t ticks, boost::function1<void, Game*> f);

class lessSchedTask : public std::binary_function<SchedulerTask*, SchedulerTask*, bool>{
public:
    bool operator()(SchedulerTask*& t1, SchedulerTask*& t2)
    {
        return *t1 < *t2;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `(*_f2)(arg)` (?). I don't know what a `Task` is in this context.

Comment: Does a Task* have an `operator()(Game*)`? (hint: pointers do not normally have such an operator by default)

Comment: I simply cannot reproduce the compiler inconsistency in a mcve, no matter how arcane I try to make the Task type. Maybe there's some `#define`-driven switch happening elsewhere in he code that butterfly-effects its way to that failure?

Comment: Definition of `Task` is missing. Assuming this is function pointer (since then `(_f2)(arg);` make seance), then next line is bad `delete _f2;`. If `Task` is some class then `(_f2)(arg);` doesn't make seance and could not compile in old gcc too. I'm suspecting some nasty operator overload. Now please provide [mcve].

Comment: Definition of task there is in scheduler, post is updated.